# DotNetOpenAuth: Sign into website with Gmail account

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to test a simple ASP.NET app using DotNetOpenAuth DLL. Does anyone has a simple code example?

Comment: did you try going to google and typing in "DotNetOpenAuth ASP.NET Example"?

Comment: Ya,no example in google :) no blog

Answer (score 1):

Simple examples are included in the downloaded .zip in which dotnetopenauth.dll ships.

See https://www.ohloh.net/p/dotnetopenauth/download

Comment: Hey Arnot,i tried to use the DotNetOpenAuth .But there is this class InMemoryTokenManager.It is said that it is for samples only.what the problem with it?what thing i need to store in a database not in memory? what i want to do is something i have done with facebook.the user is asked the authorize the website,yes==>pass ,username==>redirection to my website.

Comment: InMemoryTokenManager dumps all tokens on every web site recycle, so it's a very poor user experience on a production site.  You should write your own ITokenManager implementation that stores tokens into your database.  Since every database is different, and there are so many different ways of accessing a db, the interface must be implemented by the site that will use it.